# How can I find a all keys inside my multidimensional array that contain a specific string?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
array(1) {
          ["farm"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["horse"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["horseman"]=>
              array(4) {
                  ["fred1"]=>
                  string(5)"fred1"
                  ["fred2"]=>
                  string(9) "fred2"
                  ["fred3"]=>
                  string(19) "fred3"
                  ["fred4"]=>
                  string(24) "fred4"
              }
              ["cat"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["john"]=>
                string(4) "john"
              }
            }
            ["folder2"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["cat"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["sam"]=>
                string(3) "sam"
                ["cat"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["john"]=>
                  string(4) "john"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

In my array, I am searching for the key `horse`:

```
$srch = "horse";

function findKey($array, $keySearch){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (strpos($key, $keySearch) !== false) {
            echo "<li>".$key."</li>"";
        }
        else {
            if (is_array($item) && findKey($item, $keySearch)) {
                echo "<li>".$key."</li>"";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo findKey($array, $srch);
```

My result is:

horse

But I expected my result to be:

horse

horseman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comparing key and searching in sub array are two independent steps

```
function findKey($array, $keySearch) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (strpos($key, $keySearch) !== false)
            echo "<li>".$key."</li>";
        if (is_array($item))
           findKey($item, $keySearch); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested your code, but I get a blanc page

Comment: There ar some `}` missing, but apart from this your code is working very well!

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I found out that if an array has multiple arrays inside it is not displayed. I give you an example. One second

Comment: put it on eval.in by var_export to test

Comment: I updated my array in my question. In this case `horseman` is not displayed. Do you know why is that so?

Comment: yes. but add `<? before and initialize array taking not prinr_r or var_dump result but var_export.

Comment: hmm, this is strange. In my code, it is not working but I see in your example it is working. Then there must be another problem in my code. I need to check it out

Comment: I found out what caused my problem! I had to write `stripos` instead of `strpos` because my $keySearch was for example in small letters and the key in big letters ;D

Comment: Ok! a common problem - the bad test data :)